# Serial.Event() only runs once (using single char input)

Tags: serialization, arduino

On my Arduino Mega 2560, I'm trying to run a motor that turns a 20-vial container (accepting int input 1-20) while regulating temperature via PID of a separate cooler.  I am generally new to this field of technology so bear with me.  I also have an interrupt set up for an encoder to keep track of vial position.

The `void serialEvent()` and `void loop()` are the most important portions to look at, but I decided to put the rest of the code in there just in case you needed to see it.

```
    #include <PID_v1.h>
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <TMC26XStepper.h>

    #define COOL_INPUT 0
    #define PIN_OUTPUT 9

    TMC26XStepper tmc26XStepper = TMC26XStepper(200,5,7,6,500);

    int step = 6;
    int value;
    int i;
    char junk = ' ';
    volatile long enc_count = 0;
    const byte interruptPinA = 2;
    const byte interruptPinB = 3;

    //Define Variables we'll be connecting to
    int outMax = 255;
    int outMin = -145;

    double Setpoint, Input, Output;
    double heatInput, heatOutput, originalInput;

    //Specify the links and initial tuning parameters
    // AGGRESSIVE VALUES (to get to 4 deg C)
    double aggKp=8.0, aggKi=3.0, aggKd=0.15;

    // CONSERVATIVE VALUES (to hover around 4 deg C)
    double consKp=2.5, consKi = 0.0, consKd = 1.0;

    PID myPID(&Input, &Output, &Setpoint, aggKp, aggKi, aggKd, REVERSE);

    void setup()
    {
       pinMode(step, OUTPUT);
       pinMode(interruptPinA, INPUT_PULLUP);
       pinMode(interruptPinB, INPUT_PULLUP);
       attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPinA), encoder_isr, CHANGE);
       attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPinB), encoder_isr, CHANGE);
       //initialize the variables we're linked to
       Input = (5.0*analogRead(COOL_INPUT)*100.0) / 1024;
       Setpoint = 10.75;
       myPID.SetOutputLimits(outMin, outMax);

       //turn the PID on
       myPID.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
       Serial.begin(115200);

       tmc26XStepper.setSpreadCycleChopper(2,24,8,6,0);
       tmc26XStepper.setMicrosteps(32);
       tmc26XStepper.setStallGuardThreshold(4,0);
       Serial.println("...started...");
       tmc26XStepper.start();

       Serial.flush();
       Serial.println("Enter vial numbers 1-20");
    }

    void loop() {
        Input = (5.0*analogRead(COOL_INPUT)*100.0) / 1024;
        // A BUNCH OF CODE FOR TEMP REGULATION
        Serial.println(Input);
        delay(150);
    }

    void serialEvent() {
       while (Serial.available() == 0) {}
       i = Serial.parseInt();
       Serial.print("position: ");
       Serial.print(i);
       Serial.print(" ");
       while (Serial.available() > 0) {
           junk = Serial.read();
       }
       if (i == 1) {
           value = 0;
       } else {
           int num = i - 1;
           value = num * 72;
       }
       while (enc_count != value) {
           digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
           delayMicroseconds(100);
           digitalWrite(6, LOW);
           delayMicroseconds(100);
           if (enc_count == 1440) {
               enc_count = 0;
           }
       }
       Serial.println(enc_count);
    }


    // INFO FOR ENCODER
    void encoder_isr() {
        static int8_t lookup_table[] = {0,-1,1,0,1,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,1,0,1,-1,0};
        static uint8_t enc_val = 0;

        enc_val = enc_val << 2;
        enc_val = enc_val | ((PIND & 0b1100) >> 2);

        enc_count = enc_count + lookup_table[enc_val & 0b1111];
     }
```

So, originally I had the two processes tested separately (vial position + encoder, then temperature regulation) and everything did exactly as it was supposed to.  Now, I fused the code together and stored the vial position entry in the serialEvent() method to keep the temperature reading continuous and the vial position entry available for whenever I decided to provide input.  However, when I put in a value, the program stops all together.  I am able to see the number I entered (position: 5), but the `Serial.println(enc_count)` never gets printed.  On top of the that, the temperature readings stop displaying readings.

Any thoughts?  Need more information?

Comment: If I comment out all the PID and encoder lines, the sketch seems ok: it prints the analog values, and echoes any integer that is entered.  The `while (enc_count != value) {` could use a timeout.  Perhaps the encoder never reaches the desired value?  It won't get back to `loop` until it exits from that while loop.

Comment: Turns out, after some caveman debugging, the while loop that you pointed out goes on forever when I use the Arduino Mega 2560 but not on the Uno.  Reason being, I think the pinouts are not the same on both boards, so the motor can't be driven (thus the encoder has nothing new to read)...so the loop goes on forever.  So the serialEvent() function never even finishes, which stalls the whole operation.  Thanks for the input

Comment: Actually, for that matter, any thoughts on how I should handle using the Mega 2560 instead of the Uno?  I'm using pin 2 and 3 on the Uno (for the interrupts obviously), and it should be the same on the Mega...but I was reading around and someone mentioned that you should use pin 25 or something like that instead of the PWM pinouts.